# ASP.NET RouteValueDictionary contains Entry with Key "RouteModels"

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, model-binding

While implementing a WebApplication we came across an dubious entry in the RouteValueDictionary with the key "RouteModels".

Even Google doesn't give me results for that entry.
Can someone explain where it comes from? 
Does it come from the custom routes?
Or are this the values bound by modelbinding?

The declaration of the ActionMethode at the controller is:

```
[Route("User/{user}")]
public ActionResult UserForums(User user, int page = 1)
```

The RouteValueDictionary of the Request contains the following entries:

[image]

Comment: **Not sure**. but I think `RouteModels` key adds in `RouteValueDictionary` when you use `Attribute based routing`.

Answer (score 0):

> Does it come from the custom routes?

Unclear. However, route values are *completely* dependent on how a custom route class is designed.

```
public class SampleRoute : RouteBase
{
    public override RouteData GetRouteData(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        var path = httpContext.Request.Path.Substring(1);
        if (path.Equals("the/virtual/path"))
        {
            var routeData = new RouteData(this, new MvcRouteHandler());

            routeData.Values["user"] = "TheUser";
            routeData.Values["controller"] = "Home";
            routeData.Values["action"] = "Custom";
            routeData.Values["RouteModels"] = new List<RouteModel> { new RouteModel { Name = "Foo" }, new RouteModel { Name = "Bar" } };

            routeData.DataTokens["MetaData"] = "SomeMetadata";

            return routeData;
        }

        return null;
    }

    public override VirtualPathData GetVirtualPath(RequestContext requestContext, RouteValueDictionary values)
    {
        string user = values["user"] as string;
        string controller = values["controller"] as string;
        string action = values["action"] as string;
        IEnumerable<RouteModel> routeModels = values["RouteModels"] as IEnumerable<RouteModel>;

        if ("TheUser".Equals(user) && "Home".Equals(controller) && "Custom".Equals(action))
        {
            // Use the route models to either complete the match or to do something else.


            return new VirtualPathData(this, "the/virtual/path");
        }

        return null;
    }

    private class RouteModel
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

My guess is that this is either some specialized route or [filter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg416513(VS.98).aspx) that is storing extra data in the route collection. But why the author chose to store it as route values rather than `DataTokens` (for metadata) is a mystery.